# replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: javascript, parent-child, appendchild

Hi I've been checking my codes but I just have no idea why is the error is happening. Apparently I'm not getting my child values from my 
ttList.

```
<ul id = "ttList" style="list-style: none; padding-left: 0"></ul>
function creatTT()
{
    var input = document.getElementById("integer").value;
    var li;
    var value;

    if(/^[1-9]$/.test(input) == true)
    {
        for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            value = document.createTextNode(input + " x "  + i  + " = " + (input* i));
            li.appendChild(value);
            document.getElementById("ttList").appendChild(li);
        }
    }
        var ttList = document.getElementById("ttList").childNodes[0];
        ttList.replaceChild(input, ttList.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using value of Node in replaceChild method instead of Node itself. please try with the code below.

```
<ul id = "ttList" style="list-style: none; padding-left: 0"></ul>
function creatTT()
{
    var input = document.getElementById("integer").value;
    var inputNode = document.getElementById("integer");
    var li;
    var value;

    if(/^[1-9]$/.test(input) == true)
    {
        for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            value = document.createTextNode(input + " x "  + i  + " = " + (input* i));
            li.appendChild(value);
            document.getElementById("ttList").appendChild(li);
        }
    }
        var ttList = document.getElementById("ttList").childNodes[0];
        ttList.replaceChild(inputNode , ttList.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace input by `document.getElementById("integer")` in the `replacechild` as `input` contains value of the `input element` and not the element itself. `replacechild` expects an element to be replace and not a value.

```js
function creatTT()
{
    var input = document.getElementById('value').value;
    var li;
    var value;

    if(/^[1-9]$/.test(input) == true)
    {
        for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            value = document.createTextNode(input + " x "  + i  + " = " + (input* i));
            li.appendChild(value);
            document.getElementById("ttList").appendChild(li);
        }
    }
        var ttList = document.getElementById("ttList").childNodes[0];
          ttList.replaceChild(document.getElementById('value'), ttList.childNodes[0]);
      
}
creatTT()
```

```html
<input id="integer" value='6' />
<ul id = "ttList" style="list-style: none; padding-left: 0"></ul>
```